# Inversion of mouse in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have this code:

```
using UnityEngine;
public class MouseLook : MonoBehaviour
{
    float speed = 120f;
    public Transform playerBody;

    float xRotation = 200f;
    float yRotation = 200f;
    void Start()
    {
        Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
    }
    void Update()
    {
        float mouseX = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * speed * Time.deltaTime;
        float mouseY = Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * speed * Time.deltaTime;
        playerBody.Rotate(Vector3.left * mouseY);
        playerBody.Rotate(Vector3.up * mouseX);
        xRotation -= mouseX;
        yRotation -= mouseY;
        xRotation = Mathf.Clamp(xRotation, -25f, 30f);
        yRotation = Mathf.Clamp(yRotation, -35f, 40f);
        transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(yRotation, xRotation, 0f);
    }
}
```

The only problem is that when using it, the mouse is inverted on the X-axis. That is, when the mouse moves to the right, the camera moves to the left and vice versa. There is no such inversion with the Y-axis.

What wrong with this code?

Comment: Please use the correct tags! `unityscript` is or better was a JavaScript flavor like custom language used in early Unity versions and is long deprecated by now!

Answer (score 1):

When rotating an object around X axis, positive angles rotate down and negative angles rotate up. When rotating an object around Y axis, positive angles rotate right and negative angles rotate left.
Screen coordinates in Unity go from bottom left (0,0) to top right (x,y). When you move your mouse upward you get positive y values, when you move your mouse downward you get negative y values. Notice, that this is inverse of object rotation. That's why this line: `yRotation -= mouseY;` works fine (it inverts y values before rotating the object). However, for x values inversion isn't necessary since Screen space and Object space already align. You can just use: `xRotation += mouseX;` instead.

I don't know exactly what you are trying to achieve, but this looks weird to me: `xRotation = Mathf.Clamp(xRotation, -25f, 30f);`, because it clamps rotation to the left to 25 degrees and to the right to 30 degrees. Is this on purpose?

Try this code:

```
using UnityEngine;
public class MouseLook : MonoBehaviour
{
    float speed = 120f;
    public Transform playerBody;
    
    float xRotation = 0f;
    float yRotation = 0f;
    
    void Start()
    {
        Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
    }
    
    void Update()
    {
        float mouseX = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * speed * Time.deltaTime;
        float mouseY = Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * speed * Time.deltaTime;
        playerBody.Rotate(Vector3.left * mouseY);
        playerBody.Rotate(Vector3.up * mouseX);
        xRotation += mouseX;
        yRotation -= mouseY;
        xRotation = Mathf.Clamp(xRotation, -25f, 30f);
        yRotation = Mathf.Clamp(yRotation, -35f, 40f);
        transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(yRotation, xRotation, 0f);
    }
}
```